# Using debugger, view a function's output stream

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code's powershell debugger, is it possible to view a function's [output stream aka success pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-6)?

For example, consider the following simple function:

```
function lotsOfOutput() {
    Write-Output "First: $($args[0])"
    Write-Output "Second: $($args[1])"
    Write-Output "Both: $($args[0]) and $($args[1])"
    return "That's all folks"
}
```

If called with parameters like this:

```
lotsOfOutput "foo" "bar"
```

then the output will be a list of *four* items:

> First: foo
>   Second: bar
>   Both: foo and bar
>   That's all folks

With the debugger, I can see the values in the [automatic variable $args](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#args) (in this case, an array of two items). Similarly, ordinary variables and named parameters are available when present. But the thing I can't seem to see in the debugger is the accumulating *output stream*, which starts off empty and ends up as an array of four objects at the finish.

Is there any way to see the output stream using this debugger, so I can be certain what a function will return?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: Don't think so, no.